# Changing div content based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am hoping for some help using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsubt/) code from another Stack Exchange post. Below is the javascript:

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
    var pos=$('#date').offset();
    $('.post').each(function(){
        if(pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top)
        {
            $('#date').html($(this).html()); //or any other way you want to get the date
            return; //break the loop
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
});
```

I have implemented it on my own website here: http://peterwoyzbun.com/newscroll/scroll.html. When the scroll position reaches a certain point, the information in the box changes. At the moment, the changing content comes directly from the div ".post". That is, when a user scrolls to a given ".post" the fixed grey box loads what is in ".post".

What I would like to do is have the grey box display a description of what the user is currently seeing. So when the user reaches the div "content1" the grey box displays a text description of "content1". Maybe when "content1" is reached a div "description1" becomes un-hidden within the grey box?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You just need to change the value passed to `$('#date').html(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an hidden element inside each section containing the description, for i.e. :

```
<div id="content1">
<p class="description" style="display: none;">content1 description</p>
....
</div>
```

then in javascript get the description of the relevant section like this:

```
if(pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top)
        {
            $('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text());
            return;
        }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/6RHys/)

Comment: can you provide an example on how to do this with pure JS? or type script?