# How do I include hyperlinks in fixed content that changes as you scroll past divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fixed

I'm using a bit of script based on [Changing div content based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204318/changing-div-content-based-on-scroll-position)

I just want to make part of the text (which changes) include some varying hyperlinks.
For example as you scroll it shows a link to Google at one point, and then when you scroll past another div it shows a link to Twitter .etc.

I thought it would be simple as embedding it within the classed text, just like below..

```
<p class="description" style="display: none;">This is <a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></p>
```

However as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6RHys/56/, the text will change, but the hyperlink does not work.

Would anybody have an idea as to how this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `text()`

```
$('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text());
```

use `html()`

```
$('#date').html($(this).find('.description').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you use the .text() function which just gives you the innerText with HTML stripped out. It should work if you use .html() instead.