# Changing text content on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I found a solution that didn't work mainly that I want. Here it is:

[topic url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204318/changing-div-content-based-on-scroll-position)

and this solution works for me:

```
if(pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top)
    {
        $('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text());
        return;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RHys/)

but I want to change content description in gray box more smooth. I've tried to give animation in CSS for it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Where you give animation in css?

Comment: It's not really clear what it is you are trying to do. I **guess** that you should fade out the original content, then replace it and then fade the new text in but, as I said, it's not really clear what "more smooth" means.

Comment: I gave it to #date, but It didn't work for others (description two, three, four)...

What I mean is, that I want this descriptions to change more smooth. This mean that i want them to fade-in and fade-out in smooth way. No changing like one-by-one in 1 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your script a bit to detect when the text changes and when that happens I apply a small animation with jQuery. I set the opacity to a low value, e.g. `opacity:0.4` and then make a quick animation back to `opacity:1`.

This will help your user to see easier the change in the text.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
        var pos = $('#date').offset();
        $('.post').each(function () {
            if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {               
                var newDescr = $(this).find('.description').text();
                var oldDescr = $('#date').html();

                $('#date').html(newDescr); 
                if(newDescr !== oldDescr) {
                    $('#date').css('opacity', 0.4).animate({ 'opacity': '1',}, 200);
                return; 
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6RHys/145/)