# Change text in fixed div as you scroll through website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fixed

I'm trying to get the text in the fixed div to change as you scroll past the main divs that contain the images. I tried following the solution in [Changing div content based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204318/changing-div-content-based-on-scroll-position) but it won't work. Here is my attempt using that method: http://jsfiddle.net/st6q1Lmo/5/.

I'm a beginner so it's hard for me to write code from scratch. I must be doing something wrong... I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

This is my HTML and CSS without any JS (http://jsfiddle.net/7tdnw1eb/6/):

UPDATE: Thanks to the lead @tera_789 gave me, I've almost got it to work. For the first and third div it works, but for the second the content won't update in the fixed div. I know it could be because the video is only 90vh and the video itself won't scroll in the container... However I need it to be 90vh. How can I get around this? [jsfiddle.net/7tdnw1eb/12](http://jsfiddle.net/7tdnw1eb/12)

```css
body {
  background-color: #797979;
  color: black;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

#about {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.project {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content__container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#count {
  color: black;
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em 2em 2em 0;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="count">
    <p>1/3</p>
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    Wassup everyone
  </div>

  <div class="project">
    <div class="content__container">
      <img src="https://www.what-dog.net/Images/faces2/scroll001.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="project">
    <div class="content__container">
      <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/funny-dog-thoughts-tweets-1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="project">
    <div class="content__container">
      <img src="https://ksrpetcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/41059-Cute-Yellow-Labrador-puppy-in-play-bow-white-background.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [onscroll event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

Comment: Hey, I've almost got it to work. For the first and third div it works, but for the second it won't. I know it's maybe because the video is only 90vh and the container won't scroll. However I need it to be 90vh. How can I get around this? http://jsfiddle.net/7tdnw1eb/12/